# Prove that $x=-1$ if and only if $x^3+x^2+x+1=0$

Tags: proof-verification, logic, proof-writing

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $x=-1$ if and only if $x^3+x^2+x+1=0$.
This is a bi-conditional statement, thus to prove it we need to prove: 
[image]

Comment: You cannot verify that $x=-1$ satisfies $x^3+x^2+x+1=0$??? Can you compute what $x^3$ is for $x=-1$?

Comment: $(-1)^3+(-1)^2+(-1)+1=$ ?

Comment: For the other direction, you have inferred from: either $x=-1$ or $x^2+1=0$, that $x=-1$. In "logical terms", $P \lor Q$ does **not** implies $P$. You have to show that $x^2+1=0$ cannot holds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x=-1\implies x^3+x^2+x+1=(-1)^3+(-1)^2+-1+1=-1+1-1+1=0.$$

Comment: Thank you, I thought it would be much more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You did the hard(er) part.

To prove the other implication, you simply need to show that $x=-1$ satisfies the cubic equation.

Substitute and simplify!

Comment: Thank you, I thought it would be much more complicated.